# Comparing two char arrays freezes my Atmega on some characters

Tags: avr, atmega

I have problem with my Atmega16, I use USART to get char array, then I try to parse command and send output.

I have these methods:

```
void process_command()
{
    if(command_in[0]=='D'  && command_in[1]=='X') {
        // do something or do nothing
    }
    else if(command_in[0]=='S' && command_in[1]=='X'){
        // do something or do nothing
    }
    else{
        // do something or do nothing
    }
}
```

command_in is coppied  char array of input, I use this method to copy data_in to command_in char array. I use atomic because my software uses interrupts.

```
void copy_command ()
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_FORCEON) {

        memcpy(command_in, data_in, 8);
        memset(data_in[0], 0, 8);
    }
}
```

The problem is very strange, when I try to compare char from command_in[n], where n is index, to 'O' or 'M' my AVR freezes. There are some characters that doesn't work (especially 'O', 'o' or 'M', 'm'). A lot of characters works fine, I found this problem when I was trying to parse "OK" command. 
I even parsed command like "ALLRIGHT" and my uC could handle this.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what happens when your AVR 'freezes'? Also,  can you add the definitions of `data_in` and `command_in` your code?

Comment: Btw, for longer commands you could use `strncmp()` instead of checking all characters one by one with logical ands inbetween.

Comment: Your call to `memset` is suspicious. The first parameter is supposed to be a pointer, like `data_in`. You are passing the value of `data_in[0]` as an address instead. You may be clearing some important memory with that call.

Comment: @Joe Zocker volatile unsigned char data_in[8], volatile unsigned command_in[8]; Freezing means - No respond like in infinite while(1){}; loop

Comment: @UncleO I used memset(&data_in[0], 0, 8);and now my program works fine, So it was my mistake. Also there were some warnings according to memset. Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `data_in` is something like `uint8_t data_in[DATA_MAXLEN] ;` then `memset(data_in[0], 0, 8);` reads the first element of `data_in` and uses this as an address and sets the next 8 bytes of this address to zero.

You probably wanted something like

```
memset(data_in, 0, sizeof(data_in));
```

(assuming that `data_in` is an array and not a pointer. If it is a pointer you should use `DATA_MAXLEN*sizeof(data_in[0])` as size argument)